# Sort TreeMap by value using faster algorithm

Tags: java

I am trying to create a TreeMap that sorts a created map by value. My code right now is:

```
public static TreeMap<String, Integer> sortedMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
{
    TreeMap<String, Integer> freq = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            return map.get(s1) >= map.get(s2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });

    freq.putAll(map);

    return freq;
}
```

However, from my understanding, this would have a time complexity of around O(n<sup>2</sup>), and wanted to see if I could use something like merge sort or just a factor way to sort the map.

Comment: This doesn't work. The `TreeMap` would use this comparator to work out where to insert a key into the tree; but unless it's already in the map, it would give an NPE, and if it is already in the map, it would use the old value.

Comment: @AndyTurner: note that OP calls `get` not on the `TreeMap`, but on the input map. So it will work as long as the result is treated as immutable (or more precisely: as long as only keys present in the input are ever put into the `TreeMap`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer in this construction method, that's OK; afterwards, it's very brittle e.g. if you were to modify the new map with a key not present in the original. But also, it doesn't work because the comparator isn't implemented correctly :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/109383/869736 has many answers to this question.

Comment: Where does `O(n^2)` come from?

Comment: @BoristheSpider tbh, it just appeared to look similar to insertion sort, but I don't really have any basis on that, it very well might not be

Comment: This code is not even a sort, let alone an insertion sort. It's just a comparator.

Comment: @user207421 yes ik, thats why i said appeared to look similar. because of how the comparisons are made, similar to comparisons you would make when using insertion sort

Comment: Similar to comparisons you would make in *any* sort, or any search, or insert, or anywhere else that `Comparators` are used. This is a tree insert.